# For a newly created file, is there any difference between write() and append() methods?

Tags: python, file-handling

For a newly created file, is there any difference between write() and append() methods, in Python?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing an `append()` method?

Comment: I can't find an `append()` function to IO objects.

Comment: Basically I mean opening a file in write and append modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file in append mode, the seek pointer points to the end of the file (the pointer position will be non-zero if the file is not empty).

On new (empty) files, the end is equal to the beginning. So appending is the same as overwriting.

Comment: So basically you are saying that there would not be any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The `write` method overwrites the content in a text file while the `append` method appends text to the file.

If there is nothing in the file however, then `write` is the same as `append` (they both write new text into the file).

Comment: I have mentioned in the question "for a newly created file".